# Apply "AllowOverride" to a <Directory> With a Wildcard in The Path

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I'm trying to apply the `AllowOverride All` directive to all folders (folder are lowercase letters only) inside the `/home/user/web`, which means that I need to use some kind of matching rule while honoring the following principles (from Apache documentation):

> 1. AllowOverride is valid only in `<Directory>` sections specified **without regular expressions**, not in `<Location>`, `<DirectoryMatch>` or `<Files>` sections.

> 2. Directory-path is either the full path to a directory, or a wild-card string using Unix shell-style matching. In a wild-card string, `?` matches any single character, and `*` matches any sequences of characters. You may also use `[]` character ranges. None of the wildcards match a `/` character, so `<Directory "/*/public_html">` will not match `/home/user/public_html`, but `<Directory "/home/*/public_html">` will match. Directory paths may be quoted, if you like, however, it must be quoted if the path contains spaces. This is because a space would otherwise indicate the end of an argument.

> 3. The `<Directory>`, `<Files>`, and `<Location>` directives can each use shell-style wildcard characters as in fnmatch from the C standard library. The character `*` matches any sequence of characters, `?` matches any single character, and `[seq]` matches any character in seq. The `/` character will not be matched by any wildcard; it must be specified explicitly.

So, to target multiple folders at my disposal I have Unix shell-style wildcard matching and regular expressions. Regular expressions are forbidden so I'm left with wildcards.

Can this be a solution:

```
<Directory /home/user/web/*>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

or this:

```
<Directory /home/user/web/[a-z]*>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Since `*` represents any number of characters, including zero, do I need to add [a-z] before it in order to start with at least one character?

If `*` can be zero (no character) it will also match `/home/user/web/` and since the path is normally defined without a trailing slash `/` how will the path with trailing slash be interpreted?